# Writing fits files in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am using IDL version 5.5 and trying to write some output to a FITS formatted file. However, I keep getting `% Variable is undefined: TEN.` and `% Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: 'FITS_WRITE'.`

Is it just the case that IDL 5.5 is not equipped with FITS writing capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

`FITS_WRITE` is a part of [`astrolib`](https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/). You need to install old version suitable for IDL 5.5 to use it.

Comment: Is `FITS_WRITE` included in any version of IDL?

Comment: @stars83clouds No, as far as I remember. Personally I was always using library for this.